# how to handle focus lost and focus gain event using "shift + tab" and "tab"?

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

I want the ability to gain the focus on the next focusable component on clicking tab and to get the focus back on the previous component on shift + tab. So need a help on how to achieve the same.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question, what you describe is the default behavior of java Swing on Windows and probably on Linux too. Mac OSX handles tab focus a bit differently (not all elements are reachable by default).

If you want to customize the keyboard focus order and things like that, the default API to do that is via `java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager`.